# Branch.io android Referral program is working for one time

Tags: android, branch.io, referrals

I am using Branch.io for Referral Program. But it's working one time on a device, second time when clicking on the link it navigates to the app but doesn't load rewards, although debug mode is on.

Comment: based of your description it looks like the referral rule for your app is setup for the install event. Firstly, I would recommend not using a default Branch event instead define a custom event for which would can then setup the referral rule. 
Make sure that:
1. Debug mode is setup correctly and simulating fresh installs everytime you install the app on your device.
2. Make sure the Branch key that is being used by your App (you could be testing with the links for the live version of you App but your App must be using the test key)

Comment: Make sure the setup for the referrals is correct. You can refer to this blog: https://blog.branch.io/how-to-build-an-optimized-referral-program-for-your-mobile-app/

Comment: Can you share your test plan? Also, if you continue to face issues, could you write to `integrations@branch.io`.

Comment: I have used custom event and debug mode is on and I am simulating fresh install every time to install the app.

Comment: If you are using a custom event make sure the custom event is triggered, by the referring user for the referral credits to be awarded.